# How to close Explorer via shortcut in VS Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to open and close Explorer using keyboard.

I know that to open Explorer I can press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> on MacOS.

But is there a default shortcut to close explorer?

Comment: Mmm right. Is there a way to migrate a question or must I close here question and open a new one into Super User?

Comment: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/812128)

Comment: `CTRL+B` to close the side bar?

Comment: Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic here.

Comment: @Quentin That's why I haven't raised a flag

Comment: No, according to https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

Comment: Command+B toggle sidebar, ... @tHeSiD thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Command B" is the shortcut in Mac.

Answer (score 13):

If the explorer is out of focus:

```
Ctrl+Shift+E
Ctrl+B
```

(in other words)

```
Ctrl+Shift+E+(drop Shift key)+B
```

If the explorer is in focus:

```
Ctrl+B
```

Answer (score 2):

Beside closing explorer You can also toggle it.
To toggle the visibility of the sidebar in Visual Studio Code, you can add a keybinding in your keybindings.json file. This will allow you to show or hide the sidebar with a single keystroke, making it more convenient to manage your files and extensions.

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+P (Windows/Linux) or Cmd+Shift+P (Mac) to open the command palette.
2. Type "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts" and select it to open the keyboard shortcuts settings.
   In the keybindings.json file, add the following code:

```json
{
  "key": "YOUR_KEYBINDING",
  "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
  "when": "!editorTextFocus && !inputFocus"
}
```

Replace `YOUR_KEYBINDING` with your preferred key combination, for example, "Ctrl+Shift+B" or "Cmd+Shift+B".

Save the file, and now you can use your chosen keybinding to toggle the sidebar's visibility in Visual Studio Code.

This way, you can easily show or hide the sidebar whenever you need it, enhancing your productivity during development.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for either:

`View: Toggle Primary Side Bar Visibility`

or

`View: Close Primary Side Bar` (if you want to open your tabs with corresponding shortcuts)